# How to get float value from string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like

```
> 12.4N-m/kg.
```

From the above string I need to get a value `12.4`.

When I use replace all function `str.replaceAll("[^.0-9]", "")`.

This doesn't work when then string has two dots.

The location of float value may differ.

Comment: Please provide more examples of possible input.

Comment: Keep in mind that the unit might contain a digit (like in m^2) which probably should not end up in the float.

Comment: @chs what need to done inorder to avoid the condition like m^2 which is used fot specifying m-square?

Comment: I've added an answer with two proposals for dealing with m^2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First discard all non flot characters and then covert to Float like this:

```
float f = Float.valueOf("> 12.4N-m/kg.".replaceAll("[^\\d.]+|\\.(?!\\d)", ""));
// now f = 12.4
```

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of the pattern [^\\d.]+|\\.(?!\\d) ??                                                                      if possible, could you explain the process of identifying the patterns for given input?

Comment: Sure @Munesh: That regex: `[^\\d.]+|\\.(?!\\d)` means that it is matching one of 2 sub regex on either side of pipe `|`. LHS matches anything except digit or perios whereas RHS means a period which is **NOT** followed by a digit using negative lookahead.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. It would be helpful if you add this explanation in the answer.

Comment: Great answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input *always* has a space before the number and an `N` after it:

```
String t = "> 12.4N-m/kg.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*\\s(\\d+\\.\\d)N.*$");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(t);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(Float.valueOf(matcher.group(1)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
Float.valueOf(str.substring(0,4));
```

Comment: Here i cannot predict the location. It may differ

Answer (score 0):

following code will work with assumption that input string always starts with `"> "` and it has proper float prefixed.

```
int i=2;
while(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)) || str.charAt(i) == '.') 
    i++;
float answer = Float.valueOf(str.substring(2,i));
```

Comment: Still doesn't work when there is a dot immediately after the number.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this regular expression

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the previous answers leave out two points:

- There are more complicated numbers than this.
- There might be a digit in the unit which souldn't end up in the float.

Because of the second point I don't think replacing everything that is a non-digit is a good idea. One should rather search for the first number in the string:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
System.out.println("Input: "+ str);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found: "+ m.group());
    try {
        System.out.println("Number: "+ Float.parseFloat(m.group()));
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could do something like

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    if (mightBePartOfNumber(str.charAt(i))) {
        break;  
    }       
}       
for (j = i; j < str.length(); ++j) {
    if (!mightBePartOfNumber(str.charAt(j))) {
        break;  
    }       
}       
String substr = str.substring(i, j);
System.out.println("Found: "+ substr);
try {   
    System.out.println("Number: "+ Float.parseFloat(substr));
} catch (Exception exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

with a helper

```
private static boolean mightBePartOfNumber(char c) {
    return ('0' <= c && c <= '9') || c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '.' || c == 'e' || c == 'E'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the above options but not worked for me , Please try below pattern

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?");
```