# I want to convert the string to float

Tags: java, string, parsing

I want to convert `GBP 29.15*` to just `29.15`.

Can anyone please help?

I have already tried parsing to integer/float, substring etc. but getting an error.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include what you tried and what error you got,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java String remove all non numeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372862/java-string-remove-all-non-numeric-characters)

Comment: Use the `subString` method to get the part of the String containing 29.15, and then parse it. `Float.parseFloat("GBP 29.15*".subString(4,9))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`float f = Float.valueOf("GBP 29.15*".replaceAll("[^\\d.]+|\\.(?!\\d)", ""));`

It removes all non-number characters and then finds the float value.

See also: [How to get float value from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066225/how-to-get-float-value-from-string)